# C# Windows Form add, save, display and update text to list box using list and class

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am very new to coding and have an assignment where i have 4 buttons (add, delete, update and search), but I am still stuck on adding from the textbox to the list<> properly. Every time I run the code it adds a book but when I add a new book the first book disappears

```
  public class Book
        {
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string author { get; set; }
            public int isbn { get; set; }
            public string genre { get; set; }
            public int pagenumber { get; set; }
            public int price { get; set; }
    
            
        }








 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
            public Book Title = new Book();
            public List<Book> Mylist = new List<Book>();
        

    public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Book nbook = new Book();
                nbook.title = txtTitle.Text;
                nbook.author = TxtAuthor.Text;
                nbook.isbn = int.Parse(txtISBN.Text);
                nbook.genre = comboBox1.Text;
                nbook.pagenumber = int.Parse(txtPagenumber.Text);
                nbook.price = int.Parse(txtPrice.Text);

                MessageBox.Show("Book has been Added", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                Mylist.Add(nbook);
                clear();
    }
```

Comment: What does `clear();` do?

Comment: clears the textbox after adding a book

Comment: `when I add a new book the first book disappears` what do you mean? Disappears from where? From list?

Answer (score 0):

Your question states that you're updating to a ListBox using a list. The problem you are describing sounds as though the List (the data) isn't *bound* to the View (the ListBox). If you use [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) then changes to your data will be reflected in your view. One way to make this work is change your declaration to `BindingList` like this:

```
    public BindingList<Book> Mylist = new BindingList<Book>();
```

When your application window is created, handle the notification by attaching the binding to the view.

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    if(!DesignMode)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = Mylist;
    }
}
```

To make this work at a basic level, have your `Book` class specify how to display it as a string. In this case it will just show the title.

```
public class Book
{
    public string title { get; set; } = "Default Book Title";
    . 
    . 
    .
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return title;
    }
}
```

The click handler you already have should work fine:

```
public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mylist.Add(new Book { title = "New Book Title"});
}
```

There's a lot you can do to customize how things get displayed in the list box but that should get you started on the right foot.